# JS fetch unable to set headers

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, cors, fetch

I have a react application connecting to a Spring Boot backend application, I use JWT to authorize the user at the backend. I am using fetch to make the calls between the front and backend.

Whenever I try to set the headers of the call all the headers get removed including the Cookie (which contains the JWT). I need to set the headers to specify the content-type of the request.

**- Call when I do not set the headers (causing 415)**

fetch code:

```js
return fetch(`${urlApiGateway}${url}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: body,
    credentials: "include",
})
```

Call:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl-NL;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 13
content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: Authorization=Bearer_eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJjYXNwZXIubS50b3JlbjJAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiZXhwIjoxNjI1NDg2MzAzLCJpYXQiOjE2MjUzOTk5MDMsInVzZXIiOnsiaWQiOjIsIm5hbWUiOiJjYXNwZXIiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImNhc3Blci5tLnRvcmVuMkBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJwYXNzd29yZCI6IiIsInBlcm1pc3Npb25zIjoiQURNSU4ifX0.JdW1M7d8HB71yvP7dupomN-bgD_484HHbxmfnOOmvqM
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
```

As you can see the headers are present like 'content-type' and 'Cookie'.

**- Call when I do set the headers to prevent 415**

fetch code:

```js
return fetch(`${urlApiGateway}${url}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: body,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    credentials: "include",
})
```

Call:

It seems to be making 4 call, 2 with the previous fetch settings which where the same (no headers set).

2 of the calls look like this

```
Provisional headers are shown
content-type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
```

and 2 look like this

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,nl-NL;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
```

Where, as you can see, the headers are gone including the Cookie and content-type.

**- Spring boot cors**

```java
@Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(allowOrigin, "http://localhost:3000")
                .allowCredentials(true)
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS");
    }
```

I hope someone can help :)

Comment: Please post text as text, not as pictures of text.

Comment: OK, will edit it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It hadn't anything to do with the js code, it was my cors settings on the backend side. My authorization filter was also being applied to the OPTIONS request which caused a cors error (no http ok status), after changing this it was fixed.

Thank you to all who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass Authorization Bearer token as header. Try this:

```js
let yourAuthToken = .... // get bearer token from where you store it

return fetch(`${urlApiGateway}${url}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: body,
    headers: {
      'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + yourAuthToken
    }
})
```

Comment: I can't do it like this because I set the token as HttpOnly to prevent cross site scripting. Also adding headers doesn't work for some reason.